# Not matching type of LIst<> and its element - Java

Tags: java, list

I have a list of types `DataRespose`. I am using it to get a response from an external API and then to test it.

I am trying to create a new list with the same type and add a new element to it but I don't know-how.

I tried something like this:

```java
List<DataResponse> dataResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
dataResponseList.add("dataId");
```

But I am getting error of:

Required type: DataResponse
Provided: String`

I am aware that type is no the same, but then what should I add to be type `DataResponse`

**DataResponse.java**

```java
public class DataResponse {

    public final String dataId;

    public DataResponse(String dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
List<DataResponse> dataResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
dataResponseList.add(new DataResponse("dataId"));
```

Answer (score -1):

The list expects an object of DataResponse type.

```
  List<DataResponse> dataResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataResponseList.add(new DataResponse("data"));
```

Comment: This is a `copy-past`

Comment: When I tried to submit the answer, there was an answer already submitted coincidentally similar to mine.